# extracting a pattern and a certain field from the line above it using awk and grep preferably

Tags: unix, awk, grep

i have a text file like this:

```
********** time1 **********
line of text1
line of text1.1
line of text1.2
********** time2 **********
********** time3 **********
********** time4 **********
line of text2.1
line of text2.2
********** time5 **********
********** time6 **********
line of text3.1
```

i want to extract line of text and the time(without the stars) **above** it and store it in a file.(**time with no line of text beneath them have to be ignored**). I want to do this preferably with grep and awk. 
So for example, my output for the above code should be

```
time1 : line of text1
time1 : line of text1.1
time1 : line of text1.2
time4 : line of text2.1
time4 : line of text2.2
time6 : line of text3
```

how do i go about it?

Comment: >.< .. naah it's ok. im not a stats whore :P. pardon my language :P. i just want to learn throughm my questions :D. an answer would be most helpful

Comment: ohhhh u mean i should accept other people's answers? the link is too long to read!!!

Comment: You are more likely to get people to answer if you accept answers. Some of us are stats...uh...interested in stats. Also, it helps if you show that you've put some effort into finding a solution. "What have you tried?"

Comment: `using awk and grep` is (almost) always redundant.  There is almost no reason to use the 2 together; just use awk.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson i tried it with java. i could do it with that .. but the code was too long. Unix- i know the basics but im not pro in it. Especially filters. :(

Comment: @WilliamPursell yeah my bad. i meant awk or grep

Comment: k i got my answer. thanks to everyone who answered and gave their time for a newbie(noob? :D) like me :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that there are no spaces in the time and that there is only one (or zero) line of text after each time marker.

```
awk '$1 ~ /\*+/ {prev = $2} $1 !~ /\*+/ {print prev, ":", $0}' inputfile
```

Comment: +1, but note that this fails if the input line has a `*` in the first word.  Perhaps better to do: `'/^\*/ {prev=$2} !/^\*/{print prev, ":", $0}'`

Comment: hmm what William Pursell is saying is right. Although the chances of my line of text starting with a * is very low, still i would like to know how to account for that. William pursell i tried `awk '/^\*/ {prev=$2} !/^\*/{print prev, ":", $0}' inputfile`. it doesnt work as in it also ignores lines of text starting with *

Comment: nvm, i specified the pattern as \*(10times) as all my time stamps start n end with 10 stars

Comment: wow this answer is amazing man!! it even worked for multiple lines. Just too freaking good. wish i could accept twice :D @Dennis Williamson

Answer (score 2):

Works with spaces in the time:

```
awk '/^[^*]+/ { gsub(/*/,"",x);printf x": "; print };{x=$0}' data.txt
```

Comment: Easier to write the pattern as: `!/^*/`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this with `vim`:

```
:%s_\*\+ \(YOUR TIME PATTERN\) \*\+\_.\(\[^*\].*\)$_\1 : \2_ | g_\*\+ YOUR TIME PATTERN \*\+_d
```

That is search for `TIME PATTERN` lines and saves the time pattern and the next line if it's not started with `*`. Then create the new line from them. Then delete every remaining `TIME PATTERN` line.

*Note* this assumes, that the time pattern lines are ending with `*`, etc.

With `awk`:

```
awk '/\*+ YOUR TIME PATTERN \*+/ { time=gensub("\*+ (YOUR TIME PATTERN) \*+","\\1","g") }
     ! /\*+ YOUR TIME PATTERN \*+/ { print time " : " $0 }' INPUTFILE
```

And there are other ways to do it.

Comment: Why would you want to do it in `vim`? `sed` would be a better choice.

Comment: i have to use a regex for timepattern which would be [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]. correct? @Zsolt Botykai

Comment: Why not? Actually I added that as a choice because for some reason I thought it was a vim question (oops I'm an addict) :-) (And for some reason I don't like `sed`'s handling of action on multiple lines (I *know* how to do it, just don't like it...)

Comment: @ganducoder that regex matches 99:99:99 which is not a real time spec. As far as I see.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson you are right (and I used to, sometimes, so my colleagues (C# programmers) sometimes come to me ;-)). Or `perl`.

Answer (score 1):

In awk, see :

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
    BEGIN{
        t=0
    }
    {
        if ($0 ~ " time[0-9]+ ") {
            v=$2
            t=1
        }
        else if ($0 ~ "line of text") {
            if (t==1) {
                printf("%s : %s\n", v, $0)
            } else {
               t=0;
            }
        }
    }
' FILE
```

Just replace `FILE` by your filename.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\*\+ \S\+.*/!d;s/[ *]//g;$!N;/\n[^*]/!D;s/\n/ : /' file
```

Explanation:

- Look for lines beginning with `*`'s if not delete. `/^\*\+ \S\+.*/!d`
- Got a time line. Delete `*`'s and spaces (leaving time). `s/[ *]//g`
- Get next line `$!N`
- Check the second line doesn't begin with `*`'s otherwise delete first line `/\n[^*]/!D`
- Got intended pattern, replace `\n` with spaced `:` and print. `s/\n/ : /`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ if( $0 ~ /^\*+ time[0-9] \*+$/ ) { time = $2 } else { print time " : " $0 } }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ uniq -f 2 input-file | awk '{getline n; print $2 " : " n}'
```

If your timestamp has spaces in it, change the argument to the `-f` option so that `uniq` is only comparing the final string of `*`.  Eg, use `-f X` where X-2 is the number of spaces in the timestamp.  Also if there are spaces in the timestamp, the awk will need to change.  Either of these will work:

```
$ uniq -f 3 input-file | awk -F '**********' '{getline n; print $2 " : " n}'
$ uniq -f 3 input-file | awk '{getline n; $1=""; $NF=""; print $0 ": " n }'
```